# Using -limit tag with ogr2ogr and -where takes too long

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, ogr, ogr2ogr

I am running some `ogr2ogr` commands to extract some data from OSM dataset. Since I don't want to extract all features of some condition because I can't see them all and is takes too long I am trying to use `-limit` tag in my command but execution takes too long again.

Here is my command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" bldg_house.gpkg us-latest.osm.pbf -where "building='house'" multipolygons -limit 10 -overwrite
```

I assume that this can be done using an `-sql` tag with limit inside query but I am just wondering I am doing something wrong when I use `-limit` tag.

Comment: Can you paste here output of `ogrinfo -so -al bldg_house.gpkg`?

Comment: Try if `ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from multipolygons where building='house' limit 10" us-latest.osm.pbf` is faster.

Comment: It look like it is not any faster, after getting a message that pbf file is read using OSM driver I am still waiting for the command to finish. @user30184

Comment: @ElioDiaz Since it takes too long to create bldg_house.gpkg it there any point in doing this? When I execute ogr2ogr command, file bldg_house.gpkg is created but no data is written until command is finished.